# SQL Server: copy data from one column to another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, copy

I have two tables with the same column `anomaly_id`. I want to copy the row of `anomaly_id` from the first table to the second table using this code

```
UPDATE amb.anamoly_log_update
SET anamoly_id = t2.anomaly_id
FROM amb.anamoly_log_update t1 
INNER JOIN amb.anomaly_fee t2 ON t1.anamoly_id=t2.anomaly_id
```

Even after I did that it shows 0 rows affected, when there is data in `amb.anomaly.fee` (source table)

Please help

**Edit:** Comment [from post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8959781/1158170): I just want to copy all the `anamoly_id` from `amb.anamoly_fee` to `amb.anamoly_log_update`. My code might be nonsensical. Please do review it.

Comment: And that `SET anamoly_id ` wrong column name is a typo - right?? Is it that column in your target table really called something else than in the source table (you said in the beginning the column names were identical.....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy the id from anomaly_fee to anamoly_log_update use :

```
INSERT INTO anamoly_log_update (anamoly_id)
      SELECT anamoly_id FROM anomaly_fee
```

with both columns it looks like that:

```
INSERT INTO anamoly_log_update (anamoly_id,PID)
      SELECT anamoly_id,PID FROM anomaly_fee
```

Comment: Thanks Rauschen.It was so simple,and i was wrappinf my head around it bad.Question answered

Comment: You can mark the answer as "accepted" than it will be shown as first answer under you question .. and other see that the problem is solved

Comment: @user1151462: This thread will help you to see how, when, why to accept an answer and what answer to accept: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You only would copy the data if they where in both tables .. and then there is nothing update because you do not change the data => 0 rows affected

```
ON t1.anamoly_id=t2.anomaly_id
```

please think about what you really want to do and change your description ..

Comment: I am new to sql i just want to copy data from a filled column to a empty one on the next table

Comment: I understand that but currently you have two filled columns .. please describe the table structure better ... Or maybe an INSERT is what you want

Comment: table 1 stu_id  PID anamoly_id ||table 2 PID Anomaly_id||Table 1(amb.anamoly.fee is full and Table 2 (amb.anamoly_log_update) is empty.I want to copy all the data from anamoly ID in table 1 to the anamoly_id column in table 2

Comment: can you please update the question with tables schemas? I don't understand your previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Does amb.anamoly_log_update contain at least one row corresponding to the anamoly_id that's present in amb.anamoly_fee? You are trying to join on two tables on anamoly_id.

Comment: actually no, i just want to copy all the anamoly_id from amb.anamoly_fee to amb.anamoly_log_update.My code might be nonsensical.Please do review it.

Comment: INSERT INTO anamoly_log_update (anamoly_id) SELECT anamoly_id FROM anamoly_fee

Comment: @user1151462 Please accept the answer, if it served the purpose

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide other linkage between tables than `t1.anamoly_id=t2.anomaly_id` or the query will do nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into amb.anamoly_log_update as t1
    using amb.anomaly_fee as t2
       on  t1.anamoly_id=t2.anomaly_id
when matched then
    update set t1.anamoly_id = t2.anomaly_id
```